# How to use selenium to scrape pdfs from java rendered pages>

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to scrape links such as [here](https://hpvchemicals.oecd.org/UI/SIDS_Details.aspx?id=1034897e-e7bb-4603-900a-9f3208a8354b) and download the pdf files.
I've tried selenium, as follow:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Set up the web driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # You can change this to the appropriate driver

# Navigate to the website
website_url = "https://hpvchemicals.oecd.org/UI/SIDS_Details.aspx?id=1034897e-e7bb-4603-900a-9f3208a8354b"
driver.get(website_url)

# Wait for the JavaScript content to load (you might need to adjust the wait time)
import time
time.sleep(5)  # Wait for 5 seconds

# Find and extract the PDF links
pdf_links = []
elements = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,  'OECD Agreed Conclusions')
for element in elements:
    pdf_links.append(element.get_attribute('href'))
```

also tried:

```
driver.find_element_by(by.xpath,'//a[contains(@href, ".pdf")]')
```

neither return anything.

Comment: why would it not work if they are javascript generated pages, or rust pages, or php pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about java rendered pages. It's about "how Selenium works with contexts".

In you case block with pdf links is located in `iframe` with locator `.List_Data_iframe iframe'`, so to get ability to get your links you should switch context to it.

Then you should find elements with a tag that contain text ".pdf" (that's the only unique condition I found for that links)

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
url = "https://hpvchemicals.oecd.org/UI/SIDS_Details.aspx?id=1034897e-e7bb-4603-900a-9f3208a8354b"

driver.get(url)
next_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.List_Data_iframe iframe')))
driver.switch_to.frame(next_button)

pdf_links = []
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,  "//a[contains(.,'.pdf')]")
for element in elements:
    pdf_links.append(element.get_attribute('href'))
```